# Application of Bézout's Theorem \ Induction

Tags: abstract-algebra, induction

Let $a$ and $b$ be relatively prime integers, and suppose that $c$ is an integer and let $n$ be a positive integer such that $a$ divides the product $b^n c$, then $a$ divides $c$

Im not sure how to approach this problem. If and b are relatively prime i know we they can be expressed as
$$1=ar+bs, r,s \in Z$$
And if $a$ divides the product of $b^n c$, that can be expressed as

$$b^n c =ak, k \in Z$$

Im not sure how to approach this problem with induction or how the two expressions work together.

Comment: Do you know how to show with the same assumptions that if $a$ divides $bc$, $a$ must divide $c$? Try to go from there

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then also $a$ and $b^n$ are coprime (prove it).

Since $1=ah+b^nk$, for some $h$ and $k$, you can write
$$
c=c1=ach+b^nck
$$

Answer (score 2):

Raise the equation $ar+bs=1$ to the power of $n$, collect the first $n$ terms (on the LHS) together and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
aR+b^nS=1.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now multiply this by $c$ and use $b^nc=ak$
\begin{eqnarray*}
a(cR+kS)=c,
\end{eqnarray*}
so $a$ divides $c$.

Comment: Raise the equation $ar+bs=1$ to the power of $n$, collect the first $n$ terms (on the LHS) together and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
a\underbrace{(a^{n-1}r^n+\binom{n}{1}a^{n-2}r^{n-1}bs+ \cdots+\binom{n}{n-1}b^{n-1}s^{n-1})}_{R}  +b^{n} s^{n}\\
aR+b^nS=1.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then, for any $n\ge 0$, $a$ and $b^n$ are coprime too.

Next, apply *Gauß' lemma*.